# Finding the visible area of a point

Tags: c++, geometry

There's a triangle and a point lying outside it. We need to find the summary length of triangle sides that are visible from the point.[image]

In this case the answer is AB+BC.

As input there are coordinates of the points.

*So the question is how to solve it in C++?*

P.S. In my opinion we need to find ρ(P;each of the points) and watch if this distance intersect with any of the triangle's sides. Then choose the two farthest points, which met the condition, and find the sum of the side(s).

Comment: This is a mathematical problem until you have a formula, and when you have that only *then* is it a programming problem. A good first stop would be the [Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: Use the Law of Sines: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines

Comment: @tadman No, as the points can change their location. I want to know how to find the closest sides of the triangle to the point. In geometry I can just see them on a picture like that one.

Comment: Seriously, **math** can handle this, and once you have a formula you can try and implement it in C++. Until then you've got nothing but a diagram and that won't compile. I hope you can see the problem here. Take this to the Math forum, get an answer, and once you do, the C++ solution should be far more obvious. This problem was trivial to even the ancient Greek mathematicians thousands of years ago, it's all a matter of knowing the mathematical principles to apply.

Comment: geometry is not about what you "see on a picture", just because you can see the solution on a picture doesnt mean that you can skip solving the problem on a formal basis before writing code for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define an *order* for the triangle vertices. Let it be *counter-clockwise*. Your triangle is ACB (clockwise order would be ABC).

The point sees an edge if it's located in the right semi-plane that the edge defines.

This formula:

```
res = (y2 - y1)*(px - x1) - (x2 - x1)*(py - y1)
```

gives info about what semi-plane is (px,py) relative to (x1,y1)-(x2,y2) segment. Just get the sign of `res`.

You analize the three segments of the triangle an get those that the point is on the right side.

Choosing the other order changes the sign.

Comment: Does this work for negative coordinates?

Comment: Of course. Coordinates are just numbers. The formula works. The only issue is when the point is very very very near to the segment, because numerical imprecisions may give you a wrong result.